# UICollectionView - why frame label not work In the first and second cell - swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

my code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? GuideGalleryCell
    cell!.configureCell(listImages[indexPath.row])
    return cell!
}
```

the code - func configureCell:

```
func configureCell(_imageText:ImageText){
    imageText = _imageText

    image = System.retrieveImage(imageText.nvImage, fromCity: System.instance().currentOrder.packageName)
    imageView.image = image
    //        if let text = imageText.nvText{
    lblTitle.text = imageText.nvText
    var s:NSString=imageText.nvText

    var frame =  self.viewLblTitle.frame
    frame.origin.y = self.bounds.size.height
    self.viewLblTitle.frame = frame

    var frmageImage = image.size
    if(!(s.isEqualToString("")))
    {

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, animations: { () -> Void in
            if self.image.size.height > self.image.size.width{
                var newY =  (self.image.size.height - self.viewLblTitle.frame.size.height)
                var frame =  self.viewLblTitle.frame
                frame.origin.y = newY
                self.viewLblTitle.frame = frame
            }else{
                var t = (self.bounds.size.height - 64 - self.image.size.height)/2
                var newY =  self.image.size.height - self.viewLblTitle.frame.size.height + t
                println(newY)
                var frame =  self.viewLblTitle.frame
                frame.origin.y = newY
                self.viewLblTitle.frame = frame
            }
        })

    }
}
```

the frame of the viewLblTitle does not work the first and second cell only following cells it works, why?
What could it be? 
When I Come back into the second and first cells it has been working well,

weird, does not it?
Thank watches!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works!
I added:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
```

Before calling the function configureCell

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell:GuideGalleryCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GuideGalleryCell
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        cell.configureCell(self.listImages[indexPath.row])
    }
    return cell
}
```

Now it works good!!! :)